# как задать свойство элементу по завершении цикла в котором работает ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, циклы

```
    $("#send").click(function(){
            var btn = $(this).button('loading');
            var from = $("#from").val();
            var spl = from.split("\n");
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < spl.length; ++i){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "xxx.php",
                    data: {
                        to: "send",
                        data:spl[i],
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        var ret = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //обрабатываем ответ
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            btn.button('reset'); //вот эту кнопку мне нужно ресетнуть по окончании обработки

        });
```

Comment: @Grundy - тут дело не столько в замыкании с `i`, сколько в том, что счетчик цикла станет равен `spl.length` еще до вызова первого `success`.

Comment: @Igor, да, это именно проблема с замыканием. По ссылке - как раз пример с циклом, один в один

Comment: @Igor, ну либо я опять прочитал наискосок и не понял что хотелось :-D

Comment: @Grundy - да, пардон, согласен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать счетчик цикла для определения вызова последнего обработчика `success` по двум причинам. Первая - цикл завершится до вызова первого обработчика. Вторая - порядок вызова обработчиков может быть произвольным, а не таким же как порядок вызовов `$.ajax`.

```
$("#send").click(function(){
  var btn = $(this).button('loading');
  var from = $("#from").val();
  var spl = from.split("\n");
  var i;
  var completeCount = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < spl.length; ++i){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "xxx.php",
      data: {
        to: "send",
        data:spl[i],
      },
      success: function(data){
        var ret = $.parseJSON(data);
        //обрабатываем ответ
        console.log(data);
      },
      complete: function() {
        completeCount++; 
        if(completeCount == spl.length){
          btn.button('reset');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Так как `$.ajax` возвращает `promise` реализованный в `jQuery`, можно воспользоваться этим и собрать все запросы, и выполнить функцию по окончании всех

```
var reqs = [];
for(i = 0; i < spl.length; ++i){
    reqs.push($.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
            var ret = $.parseJSON(data);
            //обрабатываем ответ
            console.log(data);
            //проверка внутри success не нужна так как будем ждать promise
        }
    });
}

$.when.apply($, reqs).then(function(){
    // здесь все запросы уже завершены
    btn.button('reset');
})
```

Здесь [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) - функция которая принимает параметрами promise, например

```
$.when(a,b,c).then(...)
```

Но так как данная функция не принимает массив, используется подход с [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Таким образом мы вызываем функцию `$.when` и передаем ей массив наших promises. Эта функция в свою очередь опять возвращает `promise`, которые перейдет в состояние готов, когда все переданные promise - будут в этот состоянии.

То есть это аналог вызова

```
$.when(req)
```

для случая когда `req` - массив, а функция не рассчитана на прием массива.

Comment: мне совсем не понятна вот эта конструкция $.when.apply($, reqs).then(function(){}) можете мне пояснить что она делает

Comment: @user193361, дополнил ответ. Так стало понятнее?